# use colar for multiple api requests Laravel

Tags: laravel

I do not have much experience, I have the following problem with an api that receives multiple requests I would like to implement laravel queues to give a better response to those multiple requests, but I do not know how to do it.

thanks
my controller
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56LDg.jpg)

my jobs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fv3BT.jpg)

Comment: Welcome! Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. 
We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. 
You are expected to try to write the code yourself. 
Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), 
read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and 
[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: maybe I asked the wrong question, I don't expect you to do the job for me, I have already tried to implement it, I have researched it, it just doesn't work for me, I would like to know where my mistake is.